# How to animate horizontal bar with right cap, by UIView animation in iPhone

Tags: animation, uiview

I got wiered but unsurprising animation from call UIView animation, I don't know if it works the same by using CALayer animation. I guess it is.

please see this picture: what I want is to animate a horizontal bar growing horizontally, what I do is:

Subclass a UIView, called UIViewBar, and in its drawRect:rect method, I draw the shape of rectangle and a right cap, it's done by

```
CGContextMoveToPoint A
CGcontextAddLineToPoint B
CGContextAddArcToPoint D
CGContextAddLineToPoint C
//then close the path and fill the context
```

Then I call this UIViewBar (initWithFrame:rect) in my UIViewController, and the shape is what I want, looks fine. **BUT** when I perform [UIView animation] say from original **rect** to **rectGrew** it does not perform nicely. Instead, it perform as the picture says.

Well, after thinking, it's not totally unreasonable because when the UIView horizontally stretches itself, it does not know the cap will not be changed. So is there another way to do this?

[image]

Actually, I'm very new to drawing, graphic, and animation. What I know is that **(if wrong please kindly correct me):**

1. If I want to "draw something", I should override the UIView's drawRect method, and this is done by initing the UIView, should not or better not to be called outside. Say I drew a rectangle in a UIView by CGContextFillRect.....
2. But what if I want to animate this rectangle? I cannot make animation based on Quartz2D, but from UIView animation or CALayer(deeper tech), so What I have to do is to make the rectangle itself as a seperate UIViewRect seperately, so I can call the [UIViewRect animation] method, **AM I RIGHT ON THIS**
3. If so, I have to make every rectangle that I want to animate to be UIView respectively. Doesn't it affect performance? Or it is just the way apple prefers to do ?

Any suggestion will be much helpful, **GREAT thanks.**

Comment: BTW, the line BD should not exist, I don't know how to delete it in Illustrator.....please ignore it

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it's the first time that no answer posted at all! TO answer my question: it requires to consider animate custom property of CALayer. The custom property is the AB width (the width without cap width, that should work). If someone wants detailed code. Please google custom property animate in CALayer.